# Converting 0 to blank in empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to switch all of the 0's that show up in the empty cells and make them blank. I was looking around for the answer to this question, but the closest I could come up with is this. This code did not work, but I am wondering if at least part of it was correct.

```
aArray(5) as variant

Range("A1:AP252") = aArray()
```

So once again, I want to create a code to change all the 0's in the empty cells and make them blank. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using Macro Recorder:

```
Range("A1:AP252").Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
```